# Getting the Scope Resolution Operator example from php.net to run on PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php

I'm just discovering **scope resolution operators** in PHP for the first time so I am trying to understand how they work. [I viewed example #1 on the php.net page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), and have insured I'm on PHP5.2+, **however when I run the code:**

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    const CONST_VALUE = 'A constant value';
}

$classname = 'MyClass';
echo $classname::CONST_VALUE; // As of PHP 5.3.0

echo MyClass::CONST_VALUE;
?>
```

**However, I get the following error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM,
>   expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /var/www/temp/scope.php on
>   line 7

Comment: So are you running php 5.2 or php 5.3?

Comment: This code works properly. Outputs `A constant valueA constant value`

Comment: Sorry I thought I read somewhere that this worked on PHP5.2+, I am on PHP Version 5.2.17 but I see that it needs PHP5.3. I guess I need to update.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't realise that the code only worked on PHP5.3+, I upgraded and things are working fine.